# Maven parent project shows SVN change but children don't

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, subclipse, tycho

I'm experiencing an issue with `Eclipse Mars` and `Subclipse` in a `Maven Tycho` project. I got the following setup:

[image: Project Explorer]

As you can see Subclipse states that there's some change in the parent project. Despite of this children projects don't show any change. Correct is: there is no change.

I've just made a fresh checkout and `mvn install` of parent project. When I do a SVN synchronize on all children projects it shows nothing to commit (or update of course).

[image: Sychronize children]

But when I do the same on parent project it says that I should add the `target` directories of children projects.

[image: Sychronize parent]

Questions is: **How can I stop Subclipse from showing this wrong change notifications?**

Additional information: in project explorer `target` directories are shown as ignored by svn:

[image: Target directory]

Edit: it's not a problem with SVN configuration as you can see from following picture. TortoiseSVN is displaying it correctly in file explorer.

[image: File explorer]

Comment: Wow, that was a quick downvote! Please comment what I can make clearer when you downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Subclipse nor Maven.

This is related to how SVN works.If you do the same with Tortoise SVN you will see the same thing. The "target" folders are created by Maven when you are compiling or packaging something. This is where Maven works. So it is normal that Subclipse is saying you that they are new, and *ASK* you if you want to put them in SVN or not.

In general, you should ignore the "target" folders and commit this ignore property folder to SVN. Then for all others developers the "target" folder will be ignored.

I had a lot of issues with SubClipse or Subversive and decided to use Tortoise SVN which really better than Eclipse plugins. The plugins are buggy...

So to solve easily your issue, right-click and select ignore the folder because Subclipse didn't understand the SVN properties...

Comment: I'm sorry but it's a problem with Subclipse and Maven. As you say TortoiseSVN is a good tool. When I'm viewing my project in file explorer TortoiseSVN doesn't state a change at parent project. So it displays it correctly. Furthermore adding `target` directories to svn:ignore is not possible because it is already ignored. So I'm afraid that's no solution :(

Comment: @Alex But the picture shows that 'plugin/target/' is shown as new which means you didn't set 'svn:ignore' correctly on the ´plugin` folder, cause `svn:ignore` is not working recursively.